# I can't get Django custom error pages to work

Tags: django, error-handling, django-templates

I am trying to get custom error pages (404 & 500) to work in my Django application.

So far I have the following:

urls.py

```
handler404 = views.error_404
handle500 = views.error_500
```

views.py

```
def error_500(request, exception):
    return render(request, '500.html', status=500)

def error_404(request, exception):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)
```

DEBUG is set to FALSE.

However when I try access an error page I get the following error:

> "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."

Which (obviously) is not my error template.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You have a typo - `handle500` should be `handler500`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `urls.py` file.
Use:

```py
handler500 = views.error_500
```

Instead of:

```py
handle500 = views.error_500
```

Here is the [Django docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#handler500) for more detail.
PS: You can also pass the path of your custom view as a string like this.

```py
handler500 = "your_app.views.error_500"
```

This is just a matter of preference.